# When I select a material in doesn't appear in the Compositing Editor

Tags: materials, node-editor

Even though I am using the Cycles render engine and I have also ticked the use nodes box,
no nodes appear when I select a material. Also I cant find any shader in the node editor!
[image]

[image]

These nodes appeared when I opened the editor. Can anyone see whats the problem? I am new to blender!

Comment: I am stupid... Thanks!

Comment: Concept misunderstanding ...  I say :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Material* appears in *Shader* editor. In *Compositor* appears render.
If you dont see nodes in *Shader* editor, go to **View > View All**

[image]